# How to load image from cache in parallel with Glide?

Tags: android, parallel-processing, android-glide

I load some images only from cache, but I noticed, that images are not loaded in parallel, but first one and shortly after that second.

```
    Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(url)
            .onlyRetrieveFromCache(true)
            .into(imageView);
```

Seems that Glide load images from queue, one by one, not in parallel. How to change this?

Comment: Use Listener for loading the images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Glide - how to load multiple images in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012504/glide-how-to-load-multiple-images-in-parallel)

Comment: @Farid No, because it has nothing to do with network...

Comment: @Michalsx How did you conclude that cached images are loaded one-by-one?! This may help to find an answer. Also, there could be other reasons to make such impression; e.g. small pictures loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set multithreaded disk executor (`setDiskCacheExecutor`). Check https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html for details

Comment: I checked docs and I didn´t find way to do it. This is why I asked here. Redirecting to documentation is not the answer.

Comment: `@GlideModule
public class YourAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
  @Override
  public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    final UncaughtThrowableStrategy myUncaughtThrowableStrategy = new ...
    builder.setDiskCacheExecutor(newDiskCacheExecutor(myUncaughtThrowableStrategy));
    builder.setResizeExecutor(newSourceExecutor(myUncaughtThrowableStrategy));
  }
}`

Comment: I do not understand, how I can set number of parallel work with code above. There is no number. Could you clarify this?